# fb_xdm_frame_https permission denied with AJAX

Tags: facebook-graph-api, jquery, facebook-comments

I am loading the api like so:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div> 
<script> 
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() { 
        FB.init({ 
        appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID', // App ID 
        channelURL : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File 
        status     : true, // check login status 
        cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session 
        oauth      : true, // enable OAuth 2.0 
        xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML 
        }); 
    }; 

    (function(d){ 
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;} 
    js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true; 
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/el_GR/all.js"; 
    d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js); 
    }(document)); 
</script>
```

I am opening a page through a jQuery UI dialog and reparsing the #comments section with:

```
<script>FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('comments'));</script>
```

While on the non-ajax loaded page works fine, when I am opening it from the dialog it gives the error (on the js console):

```
Permission denied to access property 'fb_xdm_frame_https' @ https://s-static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v1/yt/r/Via9RsGlPnX.js:66
```

and it looks as if it still is loading (the gif keeps playing)
[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a url where this can be seen happening?

Comment: Sean, no, I abandoned the idea and implemented my custom comments. Just for reference it was happening when you were clicking http://www.menufesto.gr/goodys/ one of the foods that opens the dialog.

Answer (score 1):

**I think you are not loading javascript sdk properly. Try this code**

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
     FB.init({
          appId      : 'appid', // App ID
          channelUrl : 'http://www.url.com', // Channel File
          status     : true, // check login status
          cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
          xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
     });
};

 (function(d){
      var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
      js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
      ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
 }(document));
```